# Bootloader missing in new Windows 8.1 installation

Tags: windows-8.1, uefi, bootloader

I installed a new SSD in my laptop and installed Windows 8.1 on it. I did not remove my existing HDD that also has Windows 8.1 on it. I set the new drive to boot first in BIOS boot priority. However, the drive is skipped over on boot. I can select the drive in Windows Boot Manager and it fires up without problems, but it would be nice if I could restore the bootloader so it boots first as intended. I have tried following guides to booting into advanced recovery options and entering various diskpart and bootrec commands in the recovery command line, but no attempts to restore the bootloader have been successful. At one point, when trying to set the new drive as the active disk in diskpart, I got a message about the disk not being a valid MBR disk. I have read that booting with UEFI shouldn't be an issue, but I can't get it to boot without using Windows Boot Manager.

I am not interested in removing my HDD. This is at most a minor inconvenience since I can set the timer on Windows Boot Manager to 5 seconds and automatically go into my new Windows installation relatively quickly, but I would love to restore the bootloader nonetheless.

EDIT:

I'm beginning to wonder if it's a bootloader problem or something with my BIOS. MSConfig shows the drive as the boot drive and Windows Boot Manager clearly recognizes it as a bootable partition, so why would it be a problem with missing boot files? I checked the boot mode (?) in BIOS and it's set to use UEFI, but I wonder if something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The bios skips the drive since it sees it as non bootable, the boot files are on the other drive and are shared by the Windows bootloader but not the bios.. You should have disconnected the other drive during install of Windows and you would not have this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered in my research that I messed up by not disconnecting the old drive before installing windows on the new one. I didn't know it would be an issue until after the fact. :/

Comment: You can always reinstall on the SSD with the other drive disconnected, problem solved. There may be a simpler solution to add boot files without reinstalling but I do not know how to do this.